# How to write out a non-literal string?

Tags: string, io, rust

How can I write out the contents of `s`?

```
let file = File::create(&Path::new("foo.txt"));

let s = "foo";

file.write(bytes!(s));   // error: non-literal in bytes!
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`write_str`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.10/std/io/fs/struct.File.html#method.write_str):

```
let mut file = File::create(&Path::new("foo.txt"));

let s = "foo";

file.write_str(s);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! However, it appears I was overly simplistic in breaking down my question as I was hoping the answer would scale to my real goal. Essentially, I'm trying to concat a string and a non-literal string using `write(bytes!(concat!(s, "bar")));` - but the compiler wants a literal. Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: @user3596561 Forget `concat!` exists for now. You probably won't need it for a long time. Concatenating strings happens via `std::str` or `std::strbuf`, probably `s.append("bar")` for a one-off concatenation.

Comment: @delnan Magic! Thought I'd tried various permutations of this and was just going round in circles - still trying to grok rust's type system and what can and cant go where. Getting there slowly... Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
use std::io::File;

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::create(&Path::new("foo.txt"));

    let literal = "foo";
    let string = "bar".to_owned();

    file.write_str(literal);
    file.write_str(string.as_slice());
}
```

`as_slice` returns a string slice, ie. a `&str`. The variables associated with string literals are also a string slice, but the reference has static lifetime, ie. `&'static str`.

The above is what you would do if you can comfortably write literals and strings separately. If something more complex is needed, this will work:

```
    //Let's pretend we got a and b from user input
    let a = "Bob".to_owned();
    let b = "Sue".to_owned();
    let complex = format!("{0}, this is {1}. {1}, this is {0}.", a, b);
    file.write_str(complex.as_slice());
```